# memoir verse environment, hanging indent and numbering

Tags: latex, indentation, memoir

How do I disable hanging indent, document-wise, for the `verse` environment in `memoir`, so e.g.:

```
\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco...
\end{verse}
```

Results in:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco...
```

And not as default:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
       magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
       exercitation ullamco...
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\vindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco...
\end{verse}

test

\end{document}
```